# How to expand shell variable in `tmux send-keys`?

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to script a small utility to more easily start my day with a custom tmux window.  My variable doesn't seem to be evaluated before tmux sends it's keys, however:

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_WORKSPACE=/users/me/someproject
tmux send-keys 'cd ${MY_WORKSPACE}' 'C-m'
```

is erring out on a `cd ${MY_WORKSPACE}` error because MY_WORKSPACE hasn't been replaced with the variable contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in double quotes: "cd $MY_WORKSPACE"...

Comment: This answer tells what to do but not why to do. Additionally the code is poor, it will fail for some possible values of `$MY_WORKSPACE` (see my answer). I'm not voting down only because your answer happens to work with the value in question.

Comment: It works well enough, don't confuse a simple question with reams of explanation and pedantry.

Comment: Fair enough. Your attitude doesn't really correspond with the gist of Stack Exchange though.

Answer (score 4):

`MY_WORKSPACE` is defined in the script but (most likely) not in the shell that receives the keys you send via `tmux send-keys`. The variable is single-quoted in the script, so it's not expanded. The shell in tmux gets `cd ${MY_WORKSPACE}` literally, as if you typed it. Undefined variable gets expanded to nothing.

You need to double-quote the string in the script, so the variable is expanded there. Its content will be *typed* into the shell in tmux. Then it will be *interpreted*.

In your case the variable expands to `/users/me/someproject`. This string contains no spaces nor other troublesome characters. The solution from [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1507106/432690) will work with this string. It's like:

```
# flawed
tmux send-keys "cd $MY_WORKSPACE" 'C-m'
```

*In general* this code is poor. You should at least single-quote the expanded content:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_workspace='/users/me/some project with spaces'
# still somewhat flawed in general
tmux send-keys "cd '$my_workspace'" 'C-m'
```

(I used lowercase name for the variable because it's a [good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).) The target shell will receive the expanded variable content in single-quotes. This will prevent word splitting, globbing and further expansion of `$` (if any) etc. Still literal single-quote(s) in the variable content may break the command and even inject arbitrary commands. There are ways to avoid this. Bash itself provides a convenient solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_workspace="with spaces \$foo['\" and various characters"
# safe
tmux send-keys "cd ${my_workspace@Q}" 'C-m'
```

`${my_workspace@Q}` expands to a string that recreates the original string as one word upon being interpreted. You don't even need additional single-quotes, they will be added during variable expansion.

Comment: You're a life-saver. I had the exact same issue with whitespace in the dir and the accepted solution doesn't work. Thank you very much.